# calendar wrong time after timezone change

Tags: android, calendar, timezone

I need to get a date 5 month ago from current with the first day of month, I use this code to do it:

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance()
date.add(Calendar.MONTH, -5)
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
```

It normally works fine, making from `2018-08-10T15:46:53+02:00` needed `2018-03-01T00:00:00+01:00`

But if I change timezone to GMT+7, resume app and run this code, it gives me a strange result a few days before needed: `2018-02-28T20:00:00+01:00`.

If I remove app from memory and start it again after changing timezone, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use library [JodaTime](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) then your code will look like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime fiveMonthsAgo= now.minusMonths(5);
```

Otherwise, you must manually subtract the year when necessary.